# Добавить миллисекунды после запятой в выводе утилиты date

Tags: linux, время

Читаем `man date`

```
date [-u|--utc|--universal] [MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]]
```

Пишем: `date'+10 minutes' +"%T %.ss"` Хм `17:08:54 %.ss`

Вопрос: как описываются эти миллисекунды?
И второе `,` и `.` зависят от текущей локали или можно поменять?

Comment: `.ss` - это так-то секунды. В этом месте в мане описывается сеттер времени, а не формат

Comment: мне нужно как-то так 13:45:32,023

Comment: У date есть `%N` для наносекунд

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date +"%T.%3N"
```

`%3N` - 3 старших знака наносекунд(миллисекунды)

Ставить точку или запятую вы определяете сами - это сырой символ в формате